# Copy cell from every nth row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to grab the names in every person's name from [this google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3AyaWjES1Go-NxFYryIDlo0humlvzU4_fbiwNIWwo0/edit?usp=sharing) and put it into a new column.  The names will be every nth row.

[image: get every nth row in google spreadsheet]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alternatively, also try:

```
=filter(A2:A, mod(row(A2:A)+1,3)=0)
```

Comment: @pnuts: thanks for pointing me to this article. I'd rather invest my time helping people out. At the end, isn't that all that matters ? I fully endorse your views on this matter. Cheers, JP.

Comment: I tried this, and had to swap commas with semi-colons: =filter(A2:A; mod(row(A2:A)+1;3)=0)

Comment: @Edo The use of comma's versus semi-colons as argument separators is locale depended.

Answer (score 4):

In B2 please try:

```
=offset(A$1,3*(row()-1)-2,)
```

As the formula is copied down the [offset](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) row relative to A1 increases by three, with no column offset. In the second (starting row) 3*(2-1)-2 is 1 so the A2 value is returned. In the second output row 3*(3-1)-2 returns 4, so the A5 value is returned, and so on.

Comment: Just FYI, the difference from @JPV's answer is for this one, one has to fill down to get all desired output. Whereas for JPV's, if you enter the formula in B2 it will fill down automatically.