# Google sheet IMPORTHTML function could not find the data

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the data table from this site http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/New_Home_Page/datafile/vebitda.html into goole sheets.

I have tried:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/New_Home_Page/datafile/vebitda.html", "table", 1), but this gives me a N/A
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you may try to get it via:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/New_Home_Page/datafile/vebitda.html"), 
 "offset 1181")
```

and try to remove tags with:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "</?\S+[^<>]*>", )))
```

and then use `FILTER` with `MOD` to get every n-th value and recreate the whole table

Comment: Thank you! However I don't get it to work with the Filter funtion or the MOD function... What is the expression here?

Comment: example: `=FILTER(B1:B, MOD(ROW(B1:B), 2)=0))` - for every 2nd row (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760843/copy-cell-from-every-nth-row)